# Prove that there is no polynomial $P(z)$ such that for all $1 < |z| < 2$ we have that $ |P(z) - 1/z| < 1/2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that there is no polynomial $P(z)$ such that for all $1 < |z| < 2$ we have that $ |P(z) - 1/z| < 1/2$.

I tried using the maximum modulus principle and I noted that $ P(z)$ can't equal 0 on the specified domain but I am having no luck.  Some help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of Rouché's theorem?

Comment: Yes.but I do not see how it is applicable.

Comment: Do you remember its proof?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach: Let $\gamma$ be the (positively oriented) circle $|z| = \frac32$. Then 
$$
\int_\gamma \Big(P(z)-\frac1z\Big)\,dz = 2\pi i.
$$
On the other hand, if $|P(z)-\frac1z| < 1/2$ on $\gamma$, then
$$
\bigg| \int_\gamma \Big(P(z)-\frac1z\Big)\,dz \bigg| \le 3\pi\cdot \frac12
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

The condition $\lvert P(z) - 1/z\rvert < 1/2$ means that for all $z$ in the annulus, $P(z)$ "lies on the same side of the origin as $1/z$".

This implies that for $1 < r < 2$ the curve $P(re^{it}),\, t\in [0,2\pi]$ has the same winding number around the origin as the curve $\dfrac{1}{re^{it}},\, t\in [0,2\pi]$.

But that cannot be, because ...

Comment: Very elegant; very little heavy machinery and plenty of geometry. +1.